# Bedikat chametz when changing locations on Erev Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, travel, bedikas-chametz

Suppose someone is going to be staying somewhere for Pesach (say a hotel), but he will be going there during the day on the 14th of *Nisan*. When and where should he do *bedikat chametz*?  Presumably, he should do a *bedika* in his hotel room when he gets there, but the *mitzvah* is normally done on the night of the 14th when he will still be in his non-Pesach locale.  How should he do his *bedika*?  Should he do it (with or without a *bracha*) on the night of the 14th in the place where he will not be spending Pesach?  Should he do it (with or without a *bracha*) in the hotel where he will be spending Pesach during the day on the 14th?

Answer (score 1):

[Hilchos Pesach: Going Away, Bedikah at Hotel](http://matzav.com/hilchos-pesach-going-away-bedikah-at-hotel) quoted Rabbi Blumenkrantz in 2010 (which is why the specific date was mentioned). Note that the Shulchan Aruch (Siman 436) and Chayei Adam explain that if one is taking a trip and will be away for Pesach, one should do bedikah at home without a bracha before leaving (within 30 days of Pesach).

> If one will not be at home for Pesach (and will not be able to make a
>   Bedikas Chometz on Sunday night (28 March) one should preferably ask
>   their Rov to sell their Chometz and rent their home/apartment to the
>   non-jew on Sunday during the day. {There are however lenient opinions
>   that do not require this early transfer}. Laws of Pesach, R’ A.
>   Blumenkrantz
>
> If one will be staying in a hotel for Pesach; if one arrives before
>   Sunday night (28 March) or anytime during the night, one should search
>   the room with a beracha. If one arrives Monday morning, one should
>   search the room without a beracha. Shulchan Aruch w/Mishnah Brurah
>   437:1,2, Laws of Pesach R’ A. Blumenkrantz